# Use of "to" with no verb at the end of a sentence in reference to the previous sentence

Tags: ellipses

Consider:

> *She told him to break it up*.
>
> *He didn't want to*.

I know it means *he didn't want to break it up*, but how does one explain the use of **to** in the second sentence? I understand what's left out, and I get it re: the ellipsis—but I don't understand why **to** is there at all.

Couldn't one simply say *He didn't want* and leave it at that?

Comment: You are right about 'to' implying 'to break it up.' Without that word, 'He didn't want' does not start us off knowing what he didn't want.

Comment: With transitive verbs, English prefers not to elide the entire object, but will use "it" in place of nouns or "to" in place of infinitive clauses. Compare "Is he going to bring his girlfriend?" "No he isn't going to". In some cases, omitting "to" changes the meaning, although it doesn't always.

Answer (score 1):

In a comment John Lawler wrote:

> Yeah. If the infinitive is already given in the preceding sentence (*to break it up*), the infinitive complementizer *to* functions as a pro-infinitive in the next clause, and one can omit the rest of the verb phrase.

Comment: Pro-infinitive. 87 and counting.

Comment: Especially: want to, like to, wish to, hate to, etc.